# Is there a human readable strace alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to know what files a process accesses. `strace` can provide me with that information, but the output of `strace` is rather "raw". Is there anything that provides similar functionality, but in a more human readable fashion (i.e. filter out libraries, highlight files in the $HOME directory, provide statistics on how often stuff is accessed, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guy called Ole Tange coded the tool that you're describing. Take a look here https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/tracefile. The tracefile is essentially a shell script, so make it executable and run it. The .pod file is a manual that describes how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

### fatrace

Install the **fatrace** package:

```
sudo apt install fatrace
```

> **NAME**
>          fatrace - report system wide file access events
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>          fatrace [ OPTIONS ]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>          fatrace reports file access events from all running processes.
>
> It does not report file access by fatrace itself, to avoid logging events caused by writing the output into a file. It also
>   ignores events on virtual and kernel file systems such as sysfs, proc,
>   and devtmpfs.
>
> Its main purpose is to find processes which keep waking up the disk unnecessarily and thus prevent some power saving.
>
> By default, events are reported to stdout. This will cause some loops if you run this tool in e. g. gnome-terminal, as this causes a
>   disk access for every output line. To avoid this, redirect the output
>   into a file.
>
> OUTPUT FORMAT
>      A typical event looks like
>
> ```
>    rsyslogd(875): W /var/log/auth.log  
>    compiz(1971): O device 8:2 inode 658203
> ```
>
> The line has the following fields:
>
> - Process name. This is read from /proc/pid/comm, and might be abbreviated for long process names.
> - Process ID
> - Event type: Open, Read, Write, or Close. Combinations are possible, such as CW for closing a written file.
> - Affected file. In some cases the path and name cannot be determined, e. g.  because it is a temporary file which is already
>     deleted. In that case, it prints the devices' major and minor number
>     and the inode number. To examine such a process in more detail, you
>     should consider using strace(1).
>
> If you specify the --timestamp option, the first field will be the current time.